# How to get identity element of ECCurve with bouncycastle?

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle

How do I get the identity ECPoint element (I think it is infinity) of a given ECCurve in the Bouncycastle library.
Thanks

Comment: It seems to be infinity indeed, so `ECCurve.getInfinity()` would be the major contestant I presume.

Comment: Thanks it looks like this works as both the identity for addition and multiplication. (If you want to post as answer then I can accept it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be infinity indeed, so `ECCurve.getInfinity()` would be the major contestant. It's easy to see in the [code](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/ECPoint.java.html) that it is treated as identity element.

Comment: Code pointed to is a bit old, but I presume that the EC calculations don't change that often. The method is still valid in Bouncy 1.51.